# Getting exception: Boolean value is expected, supported values

Tags: magento2.1.5

I am trying to develop magento2.1.5 module but getting exception for my admin controller:

Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)

Error log record number: 763179888

here is my controller to access from admin:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Layout;

use MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Layout;

class Index extends Layout
{
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
  ) 
  {
    parent::__construct($context);
  }

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
    */
    public function execute()
    {
      if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
            $this->_forward('grid');
            return;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setActiveMenu('MyVendor_MyModule::main_menu');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('My Module'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

abstract class Layout extends Action
{
    /**
     * Authorization level
     *
     * @see _isAllowed()
     */
     const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'MyVendor_MyModule::manage_layout';

     /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
}
```

can anybody help me what should be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

This could be related.

Check your xml files especially tags with `xsi:type="boolean"`

[Geting Error In Checkout Page Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256197/geting-error-in-checkout-page-magento/283617#283617)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `__construct()` function and send context of `\Magento\Backend\App\Action` back to parent

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Please note that the context  changes with each controller and depends on the class extended by the controller.

Comment: after adding constructor on my class, you can see my update above, I am getting this error: I am getting such error:
Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Layout::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Registry, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Layout\Index.php on line 13 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Layout.php on line 40

Error log record number: 430498555

Comment: The error which you are getting is a general error which happens when you change the parameters of __costruct() function of a controller which can be easily resolved by deleting var/generation folder in  your magento's root directory .

Also , I think you've not properly edited the code in the question  as the class is defined two times , you should probably edit that . And mark my answer as correct if it helped .