# Geting Error In Checkout Page Magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, error, development

AnyOne Tells me How to fix this issue 
This error showing in Only Checkout page.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
  0 => true,
  1 => 1,
  2 => 'true',
  3 => '1',
  4 => false,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 'false',
  7 => '0',
)
#0 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Boolean.php(40): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\BooleanUtils->toBoolean('fasle')
#1 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Boolean->evaluate(Array)
#2 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#3 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#4 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#5 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#6 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#7 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#8 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#9 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#10 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#11 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#12 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#13 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#14 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#15 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#16 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#17 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#18 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#19 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#20 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#21 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#22 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#23 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#24 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#25 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#26 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#27 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#28 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#29 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#30 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#31 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#32 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#33 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#34 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#35 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#36 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#37 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#38 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#39 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#40 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#41 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/ArrayType.php(44): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#42 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Data/Argument/InterpreterInterface/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType->evaluate(Array)
#43 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Composite.php(61): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface\Proxy->evaluate(Array)
#44 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php(370): Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
#45 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php(169): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block->evaluateArguments(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element), Array)
#46 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block->scheduleBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#47 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Block->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#48 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Container.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#49 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Container->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#50 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Reader/Body.php(68): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#51 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ReaderPool.php(105): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Reader\Body->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#52 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(325): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool->interpret(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Element))
#53 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#54 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#55 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#56 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#57 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#58 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(228): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#59 /home/khalis/public_html/app/code/IWD/Opc/Controller/Index/Index.php(62): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#60 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/IWD/Opc/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(37): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#61 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#62 /home/khalis/public_html/app/code/IWD/Opc/Controller/Index/Index.php(25): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#64 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#65 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#66 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/IWD/Opc/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#67 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): IWD\Opc\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#68 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#69 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#70 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#71 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#72 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#73 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#74 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#75 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#76 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#77 /home/khalis/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#78 /home/khalis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#79 /home/khalis/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#80 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first line of the error message, it shows that you're using an invalid boolean value somewhere in your code:

Magento\Framework\Stdlib\BooleanUtils->toBoolean('**fasle**')

Changing the typo `fasle` to `false` will fix your issue. Try doing a search through your code for any instances of `fasle` and correcting any that you find.

Comment: Bro I Check Boolean File But There No Fasle Line Please Can to tell me How I Can Fix This Problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `checkout_index_index.xml` file search for the element attribute `xsi:type="boolean"` and check the value if it only contains boolean value. I encountered this error because "isBillingAddressRequired" is set to "no"

```
<item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">no</item>
```

It should have been

```
<item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
```